# Apple Mach-O Linker Error after installing the Facebook Pop with Cocoa Pods

Tags: xcode, linker, console, output, mach-o

My project was compiling fine. I decided to install Facebook Pop for my project using Cocoa Pods.

The installation from the command line went fine.

Back in XCode, when building, I get a Apple Mach-O Linker Error (cf. log):

```
Ld /Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Intermediates/WOwe.build/Debug-iphoneos/WOwe.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WOwe normal armv7
    cd /Users/karl/Documents/Projects/XCode/CrunchyBytes/WOwe
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/karl/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Intermediates/WOwe.build/Debug-iphoneos/WOwe.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WOwe.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework FacebookSDK -framework Foundation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Intermediates/WOwe.build/Debug-iphoneos/WOwe.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WOwe_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WOwe-cpzrvvxdoeffbsebcfuellqfleae/Build/Intermediates/WOwe.build/Debug-iphoneos/WOwe.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WOwe

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what could be the cause?